# What is the T-SQL syntax to classify records based on the day and the month of a datetime variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I need to add the following logic in a `CASE` statement:

if the variable `StayDate` is between 22 December and 31 December, then classify as '1'; if it's between 01 January and 06 January, then classify as '2', else as '0'

`StayDate` is of `datetime` datatype (example: `2017-12-15 00:00:00.000`).

How do I write this logic in a `CASE` statement?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: You can use the `between` operator for this as long as the datatype is `datetime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you don't care about the year, where you want this to work on data that could span over several years. With that in mind:

```
select  case when month(staydate) = 12 and day(staydate) >= 22 then 1
             when month(staydate) = 1 and day(staydate) <= 6 then 2
             else 0 end
```

Comment: i think you missed day  <=31

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Not needed. 31 is the most days you can have; it's the last day of the month. Similarly, the 2nd part doesn't need a `>= 1` condition.

Answer (score 2):

use case when  like below if you need two separate column

```
  select case when StayDate between '2018-12-22' and '2018-12-31' then 1 end as  classification_01
    case when StayDate between '2019-01-01' and '2018-01-06' then 2 end  as classification_02 from t
```

but if you need just classification column then it wold be
like below

```
select case when StayDate between '2018-12-22' and '2018-12-31' 
      then 1 
    case when StayDate between '2019-01-01' and '2018-01-06' 
   then 2 else null 
  end  as clssification from t
```

**Note** if you just need month comparison then follow @joel solution

Comment: It sounds like he has data that spans multiple years. At very least, the sample data in the question is from 2017.

Comment: Hey Zay, you shouldnt copy everyone else answer just to make yours better. First you copy my answer and then you copy Joel. Not cool man

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i think you are wrong , i mention about joel's solution but i have not copied your answer for-sure

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
      CASE WHEN StayDate between '2018-12-22' and '2018-12-31' THEN 1 
           WHEN StayDate between '2019-01-01' and '2018-01-06' THEN 2 
           ELSE 0 
      END as clasification
 FROM YourTable
```

Comment: The example date is from 2017.